# Angular Tomcat Deployment Issue

Tags: angular

In my case I need to hit the URL by http://localhost:8080/MVR/Redirect?param1=123 and according to the value I need to redirect the URL accordingly. Here when i deploy using ng serve the URL is working whereas when I use `ng build --base-href /MVR/.`

Deployed under webapps by renaming dist to MVR and then hit the URL http://localhost:8080/MVR/Redirect?param1=123 it is giving 404 error. Please guide me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set `.htaccess` to rewrite url.
Refer to the official doc [Fallback Configuration](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples) it explains it very well.
What you need to do is to set the `.htaccess` file to this

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

EDIT: I suggest you use an apache server like WAMP, MAMP depending on your OS.

Comment: Hi I am using apache tomcat and httpd server. it is new to me. where to place this file in apache tomcat. I am not abe to access the link saying document failed to load

Comment: Does the site work in `http://localhost:8080/MVR/` URL? If so then you need to place the `.htaccess` file in the `/MVR` folder

Comment: I am not able to create a file with name .htaccess under /MVR in windows

Comment: for apache tomcat we need to put rewrite.config. i googled it but nothing works out as they are mentioning to place the rewrite.config under web-inf and there is no web-inf in angular application

Comment: My suggestion is to use a more compatible server. Angular is just HTML. You can use a simple server like apache to do the job. No need of using Tomcat.